# Iterate through boost mapped_region/memory-mapped file?

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code which loads a file into a boost mapped_region:

```
file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only);
mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
char * const data = static_cast<char *>(region.get_address());
```

- How would I iterate through the data obtained, character by character?
- Is there any way the code above can be modified so I do not use a `char*` pointer, but rather a static char array `char c[x]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
file_mapping fm(FilePath, read_only);
mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
char * const data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(region.get_address());

// Iterate through the data obtained, character (c) by character.
for(std::size_t n = 0; n < region.get_size(); ++n)
{
      char c = data[n];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a problem with the const between c and data. A value of type char cannot be used to initialize an entity of type const char.

Comment: thanks........ would it be possible to use region.get_size() to somehow create an array of fixed size?

Comment: @user997112: Why would you want to do that?